# XMLHttpRequest xml response woes with jQuery 1.4.1, how to force the request response to be processed as plain text?

Tags: jquery

I'm just playing around with jQuery and trying something that ought be simple, but it just ain't working.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url : 'http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/',
  data : {a : 'p.routes', transport_id : 'tram', t : 'xml', l : 'ee'},
  error : function(xhr, stat){
   alert('error'); 
  },
  success : function(data){
   alert('success');
   alert(data);
  }
 });
});
```

The snippet is in a test.js file and included in a test.html file which is opened in Firefox (3.6) like file:///C:/test.html and altough 'success' is shown the data is empty and through Firebug the response for XML displays:

```
X`ML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{5ac44e50-2cb6-45d1-9cfe-0b999850ecdb} Line Number 1, Column 1:`
```

Alternatively I tried that adding

```
dataType : "text"
```

has no effect, the result is still processed as xml (probably because the response has content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8).

I'm able to see the response results through Firebug if I set

```
dataType : "script"
```

but then as it isn't actually a valid js script it simply fails, Firebug displays:

```
    invalid regular expression flag t
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>..._days><types><type routes="85" city="t
```

It gets "better", if do the above request in browser and through "View Source" copy the xml to be validated here http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_validate.asp it displays "no errors found" so why won't it work through xmlhttprequest?

What am I doing wrong?

Would it be possible to somehow force the xmlhttprequest's response to be processed as text/plain?

br,
iges

P.S. I've tired the suggested dataType : "html" option (forgot to mention initially), but the "html" also does not work and in Firebug I can see the same error about parsing/moz-nullprincipal.

Also the service providing the xml data is controlled by a third party to which I do not have access, either there is a way to do this or I'll have to kiss my idea goodbye :(

Answer (score 5):

Are you executing this code from the same domain ?  (*http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee*)

Because you are not allowed to use the ajax calls to fetch data from other domains ...  (unless using the JSONP or script datatypes ..)

> When data is retrieved from remote servers (which is only possible using the script or jsonp data types), ...

Tha alternative would be to have jQuery request a local file which would receive the data server-side and serve them to the ajax request..

for example
php: [http_post_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php)
asp: [Microsoft.XMLHTTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927184623/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110100-1.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

What about HTML?

```
dataType : "html"
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

> "html": Treat the response as HTML
>   (plain text); included script tags are
>   evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You are not allowed to use the Ajax calls to fetch data from other domains unless you are using either the `jsonp` or `script` data types.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#test').click( function() {
    $.ajax({ 
    url : 'http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/',
    dataType : 'xml',  
    data : {a : 'p.routes', transport_id : 'tram', t : 'xml', l : 'ee'}, 
    error : function(xhr, stat){ 
    alert('error');  
    }, 
    success : function(data){ 
    alert('success'); 
    $('#foo').html(data);  // could also use text(data) to see XML returned as text
    } 
    }); 
  });
});
```

Assuming you have a HTML file like:

```
<body>
<div>
<h1> Tester</h1>
</div>
<br />
     <input type="button" id="test" value="Test" />
     <div id="foo">
     </div>
 </body>
```

NOTE: This appears to work fine in IE8 but not so much in FF3.6

Answer (score -1):

Doh'

tried YQL query only to find out that robots.txt is blocking :(