# Ajax/jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm rookie when it comes to Ajax and jQuery and needs some help...

The following url produces an xml-file that I want to use on my page:
http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=foo

When I use firebug it seems like nothing comes back. What have I done wrong?

This is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
     <head>    
         <title></title> 
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
         <script type="text/javascript"> 
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=foo',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error loading XML document');
                },
                success: function(xml){
                    alert("success");
                    $(xml).appendTo("#result");                   
                }
            });
        });
         </script> 
     </head> 
     <body> 
        <div id="result">
        </div>       
     </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Is that xml file on the same domain as the script you're calling it from?

Comment: When you say **nothing comes back**, I assume you mean that your `success` callback is getting called, but there's no data. Is that right?

Comment: A pure XML reply would not display in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Is your web page where the JS is running also from ws.spotify.com?  Otherwise, you will run into the browser's restrictions to prevent [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) by using the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You can use data of type jsonp to get around this issue.  Ajaxian provided a post on a [workaround](http://ajaxian.com/archives/xml-messages-with-cross-domain-json) that you can hopefully use.  It doesn't use jQuery, but it may help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your success function may be a little off:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSON return format instead of XML, there is some information concerning your case here: [XmlHTTPRequest: "XML Parsing Error: no element found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212068/xmlhttprequest-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found)

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you also use HTTPFox to look at what's happening between your script and the server