# Send HTTP Request and properly ignore the Response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

Examples abound of methods to [initiate a web (HTTP) request in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247483/393280). But, when I initiate a web request and the server return a blank response, Firefox at least throws an error:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: http://example.com/service Line Number 1, Column 1: 1 service:1:1

I am using a function similar to:

```
function RequestGET(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send();
}
```

In this particular case, the server has nothing to return and I expect that. So, how do I structure my client-side script to handle this response without throwing this error? Or, more generally, how can I handle a non-XML response properly?

Comment: I'd recommend using the JavaScript portion from [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2212068/2341603), which essentially boils down to `if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined')`.

Comment: If you want to play the modern game, `fetch` makes XHR easier in native JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For probably a defensible reason, Firefox sets the default MIME type to XML (not sure if it's `text/xml` or `application/xml`). Thankfully, the `XMLHttpRequest` object has an `overrideMimeType` method, which I can use to set the MIME type to `text/plain`.

The following function works to ignore responses, blank or otherwise:

```
function RequestGET(url, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    if (req.overrideMimeType)
        req.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
    req.send(null);
}
```

Comment: The [responseXML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) documentation helped me to arrive at this answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [`responseXML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) may === `null`

> The XMLHttpRequest.responseXML property is a read-only value which returns a Document containing the HTML or XML retrieved by the request, **or null** if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or **if the retrieved data can't be correctly parsed** as XML or HTML.

**Something like** the below will *catch* and handle the many possible returns we can expect.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    handleResponses = function( x ) {
        var s = x.status;
        if ( s < 400 ) {
            if ( s === 200 ) {
                var rXML = x.responseXML;
                if ( rXML !== null ) {
                    console.log( rXML );
                } else {
                    console.error( "Not XML" );
                    console.log( x.response );
                }
            } else {
                console.warn(
                    { 204: "No Content",
                      304: "Not Modified" // etc.
                    }[ s ] || "Nothingness..."
                );
            }
        } else {
            console.error(
                { 400: "Bad Request",
                  404: "Not Found" // etc.
                }[ s ] || "Oh snap!"
            );
        }
    };
xhr.open( "GET", "https://example.com/service", true );
xhr.addEventListener( "error", function() {
    // If this happens, the request effectively failed.
    console.error( "The internet is empty" );
}, false );
xhr.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
    // Even if the request fails, this will happen.
    if ( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {
        handleResponses( xhr );
    }
}, false );
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thank you for your link to the `responseXML` documentation, which helped me arrive at the answer.

Comment: YW. Documentation rocks \m/

Answer (score 0):

```
req.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (req.readyState===4 && req.status===200) {
        var response=req.responseText;
    }
};
```

This will capture the response into the "response" variable once the request has been completed

Comment: Including this part still throws the "XML Parsing Error", unfortunately.

Comment: Is this only when the server has no response? which line is it throwing it on?

Answer (score 0):

> Or, more generally, how can I handle a non-XML response properly?

I would give the **Try...Catch** a go.

```
try {
  // parse response data
}
catch(error){
 // handle parsing exception
}
finally{
 // buy me a beer
}
```

> Perhaps this would work, but around which block would I wrap the exception handling?

```
function RequestGET(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // set callback for xhr state change events
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() {

        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            // request is completed

            if(req.status === 200) {
                // The request succeed!
                try {
                    // parse response data
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(req.responseText,"text/xml");

                    // here your xml document object...
                    // > xmlDoc
                }
                catch(error){
                 // handle parsing exception
                }
                finally{
                 // buy me a beer
                }

            } else {
                // The request did not succeed!
            }
        }
    }

    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this would work, but around which block would I wrap the exception handling?

Comment: I extended my answer for you.